# What does `reference` shown by Visual Studio in a line before the declaration of a method means and consists of

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015 for C#, what does the `reference` shown by Visual Studio in a line before the declaration of some method actually mean?

What kinds of items does the `reference` consist of?
I.e. what are the items shown by `reference`?

Are they simply all the strings that match the method's name, or some subset of all matching strings?

For example, the reference shown in the line before the declaration of the overriding method, includes

- the definition and usage of the method being overridden in the base class
- the definition of a method from a sibling class derived from the base class
- maybe more...

I can't figure out what `reference` means and consists of.

Comment: reference means the method is used/called by other code, instead of manual reference(which you might think to be?)

Answer (score 2):

This is called [**CodeLens**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/70dbe6/visual-studio-code-lens/) **references**. References can help you see where and how the individual parts of your code are used in your solution.

Clicking the **reference count** opens the **CodeLens** window showing all the places where references exist in the solution. Hovering over a reference will show a small code snippet of the calling code giving you more context when needed.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. What are the items shown by `reference`? Are they simply all the strings that match the method's name, or some subset of all matching strings?

Comment: No, not strings, but references. Strings won't be recognized here.

Comment: can you define  "references"? I found that they are not necessarily definition and calls to the method: in the example I mentioned for the references of a override method, the references include a method of a sibling class overriding the same base class.

Comment: We have issues where it doesn't show all references. If we do find all references, we get far more results. We use dependency injection heavily, and I suspect that's the issue. Does anybody else have this?

Comment: Basically, it's where you can find the part/places of your code where you called the method, property, etc. This is just code information, it doesn't have any bearing with how your code will perform. It makes it easier for you to locate where it is getting called.